# Water in (tubed MTB) tyres for weeks after a riding through a ford - is it a problem?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire

I changed my MTB tyres yesterday for today's ride (lots of road and gravel, not much tricky stuff, and very dry, so I wanted the faster ones).  That bike with the other tyres had last been ridden quite a few weeks ago, and that ride included a ford.  When I took the tyres off there was stagnant water in them, several 10s of ml per tyre I reckon.

There was another ford towards the end of today's ride, so there will probably be some water in there again.  I reckon it gets in through the spoke holes, but then can't get out again.  These are aluminium rims, probably not tubeless ready, with rubber rim tape and stainless spokes.

Is it a problem?  Should I do anything to remove it/can I do anything to prevent it?

Comment: How's conditions in your bike storage area?  I had similar when bikes lived outside under a carport, in winter they didn't ever warm up much.  Then a new house with more garage space and its attached to house, so drier and warmer.  Bikes and vehicles definitely appreciate being warm and dry.

Comment: @Criggie an insulated but unheated garage built in to shady side of the house. Bikes dry slowly but do dry even in winter

Answer (score 3):

I did a little research and it appears that this is a common occurrence when riding in heavy rain or fording streams.

Indeed, water gets into the rim primarily/exclusively by passing by the spike nipples. Some rims include a small hole just inside the braking path (on a rim brake) that can drain water, and some pro team mechanics have added a small “drain hole” to aluminum rims to serve the same purpose (back before everyone was running carbon rims).

If you are going to ford a stream or ride in heavy rain, you probably cannot prevent it.  If you used a tubeless rim strip you may keep the water out of the tire area, but it still would stay in the rim (without a drain hole). Knowing what you have experienced, you should deflate your tires, and dismount them after any “wet” ride in order to drain any accumulated water and allow any residual moisture to evaporate, leaving you with a dry system again.

If it stays wet a couple days, it should not be a problem, but you should probably not neglect it for too long.

Comment: I can't see how a drainage hole would work - water goes downhill and any drainhole in the rim would likely end up above the water.   Any drainhole in the tyre would turn into a haemorrage allowing the tube through.

Comment: If it is close to where the rim sidewall merges with the enclosed area of the rim, and the drain hole is positioned at the bottom (directly below the axle), water could drain out.  That doesn’t prevent water from moving into the tire as water moves past the rim strip. Putting tubeless tape down for a rim strip should minimize water infusing into the tire.  The research I followed cited user experiences where they would drain their rims for up to five minutes after a an extremely wet ride/race. The reason it took so long was due to the hole being fairly small.

Comment: I've never noticed it from rain or even deep puddles on any of my bikes, but fords are deeper for longer. My tourer didn't seem to let any in from a flooded road followed by a puncture a moment later, though everything was still wet enough that it was hard to tell